# How to create base entity and base class map in Fluent NHibernate

Tags: c#, nhibernate, orm, fluent-nhibernate

I have common columns "Id, IsActive, CreateDate" in all tables. Now I want to move "Id, IsActive, CreateDate" in my base entity and also want to create base mapping. How can I achieve this in Fluent NHibernate?

Answer (score 3):

You can create a base mapping like this:

```
public class BaseMap<T> : ClassMap<T> where T : Address
{
    public BaseMap()
    {
        Id(x => x.Id);
        Map(x => x.IsActive);
        Map(x => x.CreateDate);
    }
}

public class SomeEntityMap: BaseMap<SomeEntity>
{
    public CustomerAddressMap()
    {
        Table("SomeTable");
        Map(x => x.SomeProperty);
    }
}

public class Entity
{
   public virtual Guid Id { get; set; }
   public virtual bool IsActive { get; set; }
   public virtual DateTime CreateDate { get; set; }
}

public class SomeEntity : Entity
{
   public virtual string SomeProperty { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: But where is the base entity where I put my common properties?

Comment: You have to create it but judging by your comment above it seems you had created a base entity with those properties.

Comment: @ZeeshanMehmood I have edited my solution to be more specific to your example

Comment: As per my research, best practices says that base entity should be abstract and must override Equals and GetHashCode method. Also in base class map you said "where T : Address" but there isn't any class for "Address".

Comment: This was a rudimentary example showing you how it would be possible to do what your question is asking.  It wasn't meant to show you every thing you should do in your base class.  Look at this if you want a more elaborate base class: https://github.com/nhibernate/NHibernate.AspNet.Identity/blob/master/source/NHibernate.AspNet.Identity/DomainModel/EntityWithTypedId.cs

Comment: Haha.  This is the correct answer to your question.  Nowhere did you ask for how to create a base class using nhibernate best practices.  Even if you did I doubt you would get an answer to that.  You have to do some research online and figure out what works best for you.